# Android_Home path give error in cordova

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am working on cordova 6.0 for that purpose I installed android studio 3.0.1, nodejs 6.0, jdk 1.8.162 but when I run cordova build android command. It gives Android_Home path gives error. I already place android sdk path in system variables. Can any one help to solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need paths to Java (JAVA_HOME env. var), Android (ANDROID_HOME env. var) and you also need to manually install [gradle](https://gradle.org/) and add it to your path as well.